# how to make game connect a word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

how to make game connect a word?, i was confuse to check the character

my code:

```
lenght_first_word = int(input('Lenght first word: '))
first_word = input('First Word: ')
lenght_second_word = int(input('Lenght second word: '))
second_word = input('Second word: ')

first_word_spelling = [*first_word]
second_word_spelling = [*second_word]

list_word = []
repeat = -1
y = 0
while y < lenght_second_word:
    for i in range(lenght_second_word, -1, -1):
        if first_word_spelling[-1] == second_word_spelling[repeat]:
            list_word.append(second_word_spelling[repeat])
        else:
            repeat -= 1
    y += 1
print(list_word)
```

i hope the input is :

**Input** :

```
Lenght first word: 6 
First word: center
Lenght second word: 9
Second word: terminate
```

**Output** : the second word can be connected with "ter"

**==========Or==========**

**Input**:

```
Lenght first word: 4
First word: show\
Lenght second word: 3
Second word: why
```

**Output** : the second word can be connected with "w"



if the words can't be connected the output is **"the word can't be connected"**

thanks a lot:))

Comment: its spelled "length" not "lenght"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to do it

```
first_word = input('First Word: ')
second_word = input('Second word: ')

joined = ""
for i in range(1, min(len(first_word), len(second_word)) + 1):
    if first_word[-i:] == second_word[:i]:
        joined = first_word[-i:]

if joined:
    print(f"The words can be connected with {joined}")
else:
    print("Words cannot be connected")
```

Here we loop through the shorter word's length and compare the last 1, 2, 3... letters from word 1 to same amount of letters in the beginning of word 2.

There are a few pointers with your example I wanted to bring up.

1. You don't need to query the length of the words from user, it's easier to determine it ourselves in the code using `len('word')`.
2. Casting strings as a list is redundant as well, since in python strings are already lists of characters and thus can be sliced as is.
3. You don't need two loops, since you're always comparing the first x characters of the first word and second x characters from the second word. See my example.
4. You have the index variable `i` free to use in the for loop `for i in range...:`, you don't need an extra variable to carry over just to add or subtract 1 in every loop. For the same reason, your first loop would work better as a for loop instead of a while loop.

Comment: you're program just work if only the last character is same, but i hope the longest character, for example in first input, **terminate** can be connected with **center** because **"ter"** in **"center"** has been there in **"ter"** in **"terminate"**. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Oops you're right. I didn't test the last optimization. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

search for letter in second word by comparing first letter of first word and use indexing.

```
first_word = input('First Word: ')
second_word = input('Second word: ')
index_value = []
for ind, val in enumerate(first_word):
    if val == second_word[0]:
        index_value.append(ind)
if index_value:
    search_word = first_word[index_value[0]:]
    n = len(search_word)
    if search_word == second_word[:n]:
        print(f'the second word can be connected with "{search_word}"')
    else:
        print("the word can't be connected")
else:
    print("the word can't be connected")

>>>> First Word: center
>>>> Second word: terminal
>>>> the second word can be connected with "ter"
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
first_word = input('First Word: ')
second_word = input('Second word: ')

merge = 0

for i in range(1, min(len(first_word), len(second_word)) + 1):
    if first_word[-i:] == second_word[:i]:
        merge = first_word[-i:]

if merge:
    print("The second word can be connected with", str(merge))
else:
    print("The word can't be connected")
```